# Pandas: How to find whether address in one dataframe is from city and state in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of addresses as below:

```
main_df =
                                          address
0               3, my_street, Mumbai, Maharashtra
1                 Bangalore Karnataka 45th Avenue
2  TelanganaHyderabad some_street, some apartment
```

And I have a dataframe with city and state as below (note few states have cities with same names too:

```
city_state_df =
         city        state
0      Mumbai  Maharashtra
1  Ahmednagar  Maharashtra
2  Ahmednagar        Bihar
3   Bangalore    Karnataka
4   Hyderabad    Telangana
```

I want to have a mapping of city and state next to each address. I am able to do so with `iterrows()` with nested for loops. However, both take more than an hour each for mere 15k records. What is the optimum way of achieving this considering addresses are randomly written and multiple states have same city name?

My code below:

```
main_df = pd.DataFrame({'address': ['3, my_street, Mumbai, Maharashtra', 'Bangalore Karnataka 45th Avenue', 'TelanganaHyderabad some_street, some apartment']})
city_state_df = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['Mumbai', 'Ahmednagar', 'Ahmednagar', 'Bangalore', 'Hyderabad'],
                     'state': ['Maharashtra', 'Maharashtra', 'Bihar', 'Karnataka', 'Telangana']})

df['city'] = np.nan
df['state'] = np.nan

for i, df_row in df.iterrows():
    for j, city_row in city_state_df.iterrows():
        if city_row['city'] in df_row['address']:
            city_filtered = city[city['city'] == city_row['city']]
            for k, fil_row in city_filtered.iterrows():
                if fil_row['state'] in df_row['address']:
                    df_row['city'] = fil_row['city']
                    df_row['state'] = fil_row['state']
                    break
            break
```

Comment: hey there, congrats on your 1st question, please share some code that can be used by others to help you. For example, the first dataframe could be shared like this: 
import pandas as pd
main_df = pd.DataFrame({"address":["3, my_street, Mumbai, Maharashtra","Bangalore Karnataka 45th Avenue","TelanganaHyderabad some_street, some apartment"]})

also, please share the code of your previous attempts

Comment: I added my attempt

Comment: good, your code doesn't work though. make sure you import all the packages you need and delete your variables before testing if it works. given that nobody is paid to answer questions on stackoverflow, you gotta make it as easy as possible for people to help you

Answer (score 0):

Hello maybe something like this:

```
main_df = main_df.reindex(columns=[*main_df.columns.tolist(), 'state', 'city'],fill_value=None)

for i, row in city_state_df.iterrows():
    main_df.loc[(main_df.address.str.contains(row.city)) & \
                 (main_df.address.str.contains(row.state)), \
                ['city', 'state']] = [row.city, row.state]
```

Comment: it takes approx same time to process, is there a better solution?